# Why is the .bss section mapped into a process smaller than the bss reported in the object file?

Tags: linux, memory, linux-kernel, shared-libraries, elf

I always assumed that the linker allocated the bss section of any libraries and maps it into the process. The size of this section would depend on the size of the bss reported by library.

I looked at the /proc/[PID]/maps file of a process, and computed the size of the bss section of a loaded library.

```
7f1f5561f000-7f1f55637000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3018048          /usr/lib/libpthread-2.19.so
7f1f55637000-7f1f55837000 ---p 00018000 08:01 3018048          /usr/lib/libpthread-2.19.so
7f1f55837000-7f1f55838000 r--p 00018000 08:01 3018048          /usr/lib/libpthread-2.19.so
7f1f55838000-7f1f55839000 rw-p 00019000 08:01 3018048          /usr/lib/libpthread-2.19.so
7f1f55839000-7f1f5583d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1f5583d000-7f1f55851000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3017945          /usr/lib/libresolv-2.19.so
7f1f55851000-7f1f55a50000 ---p 00014000 08:01 3017945          /usr/lib/libresolv-2.19.so
7f1f55a50000-7f1f55a51000 r--p 00013000 08:01 3017945          /usr/lib/libresolv-2.19.so
7f1f55a51000-7f1f55a52000 rw-p 00014000 08:01 3017945          /usr/lib/libresolv-2.19.so
7f1f55a52000-7f1f55a54000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
```

Here we can see that the bss of libpthread is in the address range 7f1f55839000-7f1f5583d000 and subtracting them gives us a size of **16384 bytes**.

Using the `size` command or readelf, the size of the bss section of libpthread is **16848** bytes.

It makes sense that they're different as the virtual address range needs to line up to page boundaries, but how can the virtual size be **smaller** than the size reported by the elf file? There isn't enough space to fit all the variables.

Is the linker able to determine that some of the variables in bss aren't necessary for the particular loading executable? If so, how is this done?

Comment: https://xkcd.com/979/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Here we can see that the bss of libpthread is in the address range 7f1f55839000-7f1f5583d000 and subtracting them gives us a size of 16384 bytes.

The difficulty stems from the fact that statement isn't entirely accurate.  The ELF linker and Linux loader actually do not guarantee a one-to-one relationships between sections, segments, and mappings.  The result is that the highlighted mapping does not, in fact, represent *all* of the `.bss` (as you have discovered).

Typically the ELF linker using the default linker script will create two `LOAD` segments: one R/E (for text and read-only data) and one R/W (for writable data, including the `.bss`).  It will arrange for the `.bss` to appear at the end of the segment so that it can set the associated [ELF program header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format#Program_header) `p_filesz` to cover only the initialized data while setting the `p_memsz` a larger value to add enough space for the `.bss`.

When the loader processes this segment, it will create either one or two mappings.  The first mapping will be "file backed" from `p_offset` for `p_filesz`.  Thus, the page fault on initial access will guarantee the necessary initial values.  Any space left in the last page of this first mapping will be `memset` to zero (the access itself having first faulted in any initialized values).  If the remaining `p_memsz` fits into that newly zero filled space, then that's all that the loader needs to do.  Otherwise, if further space is needed the loader will create an anonymous mapping (backed by `/dev/zero`) to cover the remainder.

Thus the size of the `.bss` in memory is actually the sum of the second anonymous mapping and the "tail" of the immediately preceding mapping.  Probably the simplest way to get an estimate of the `.bss` in memory (within the various alignment constraints applied by the linker, loader, and kernel in accordance with the various applicable ELF, POSIX, and Linux standards) is using *e.g.* `readelf --program-headers` to get the `p_filesz` and `p_memsz` for the applicable segment and subtract the former from the latter.